# Does Windows Speech Recognition produce log files?

Tags: windows, internet-explorer-10, voice, voice-command, windows-speech-recognition

Does Windows Speech Recognition produce logs of what commands have been used?

We're having a problem where a certain command either crashes or closes IE10, but we're not quite sure how WSR is interpreting it.